# VScode - Search in open tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to search for a string in the currently open tabs, only?
Notepad++ has this handy feature and I am wondering if VScode has something similar.

Comment: Answers to this question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42011289/328817

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could open a feature request - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode