# How to search only in currently open files in vscode?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

I usually work on larger projects with many files that would contain the search query. So I would open the files I want to modify and do a find/replace across all currently opened files. Can this be done in vs code?

The feature I'm looking for is implemented in Notepad++, but I'd prefer not to have to switch editors for this task.

Comment: For newer version of vscode, the correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802144/1772898

Comment: This answers for this have become way too verbose. 
TLDR: Toggle the little book icon in the `Files to include` field.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For me somehow it works just by typing `./` in the files to exclude field.

[image: Here]

Comment: Bravo! This works. Thanks. I've being looking for this since ages

Comment: Seems works, but don't know why. 
VS Code. V1.52.1, installed on Win 10 x64, open remote file via Remote SSH.

Comment: This does not work in the latest VS Code at least, and not sure why it would have worked as there has been a long-requested and still open feature request for this.  If it worked for you it prob was because you have actual files open that are on disk. VS Code can have new tabs that have never been saved and it would never work for that, as that search option shown in this question can only search files on disk.

Answer (score 76):

The ability to search **only** in the open editors is in the Stable Build v1.55.

[image: search in open editors only]

As you can see, the icon is at the end of the `files to include` input so you will have to have that showing (click the three dots `...` just below the search options if `files to include` is not already showing).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This should be edited - it's way too verbose. The answer today is simple. Click the little book icon.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver - it's got a cute little animated video for those of us too busy to read the text.

Comment: @JeffWright there used to be a lot more text :-) but looks like Mark saw my comment and reduced it. Definitely +1 for the animation

Answer (score 17):

"Search: target particular set of files #20530" located here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20530

Is tracking a search "scope" such as "all open files".

Answer (score 10):

Hit Ctrl + Shift + F and enable the icon at the end of the 'file to include' text field

[image: VS Code search toolbar]

Comment: Nice, this works. I never even noticed that icon.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a way to do this. You can make a feature request on github. I think an extension could do it though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a checkbox for this in the "files to include" field since [version 1.55](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55) (march 2021).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using Visual Studio Code itself, you can just search the file contents within the folder where unsaved files open in Visual Studio Code are located. This would be in one of these locations depending on which OS you are running:

- Linux: /tmp/ (someone else running Linux can verify this)
- macOS: ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Backups/
- Windows: %APPDATA%\Code\User\

Answer (score 1):

The answer was already mentioned (and accepted above) indeed typing `./` in the files to exclude box of the search window will allow you to only search in open files.

However the response mentioned that he was unsure why this worked. VSCode allows you to exclude all files in a directory by writing the directory in the exclude box. The directory `.` is the directory where VSCode is opened ie the root directory. The filter `./` excludes all files in the VSCodes root directory so all files are excluded. However opened files ignore any exclude filter. So if you exclude all files only the opened files will be searched.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find something you are searching for within a specific file in vs code would be:

- <kbd>Ctrl + p</kbd> then pressing `@` on the search bar.

It will give you a list of all functions on the file, which makes it easier to track something down.

Answer (score 1):

This [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shibayu36.search-in-current-file) is what I use for this purpose.
You may need to change the keybinding if there is a conflict.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).