# How to search for all files in the currently open folder / workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm searching for a particular piece of text and using the Search functionality within VS Code (Ctrl+Shift+F).  I type some text in the search box and it shows the results only from files that are open already.  How do I search for all the files within that workspace / open folder?

*(I'm quite new to VS Code so this might be something simple)*

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011289/how-to-search-only-in-currently-open-files-in-vscode

Comment: I faced the same problem just now, my solution is using the setting files.exclude to remove unnecessary files from my projects, like .git or virtualenv or temp/log folders ...  I think vs code cannot manage too many files at the same time. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you have the 'Use Exclude Settings And Ingore Files' toggled?

[image: VS Code Global Search Ignore Files]

Comment: I deleted all my user settings tried the search again and again no results.  Again, if i open three or files and run a search again it will display results in those open files but not in any others.  Interestingly, in all my react native projects the search does not work but in a project created for a web based react js project the search does work.  I think it must be something to do with the configuration of the folder structure...strange though

Comment: what happens when you specify the folder in which you know the string exists using 'Files to Include' option? Something like: `app_folder/*`.

Comment: exactly the same, it only searches for those files that are open

Comment: ok, last try then: can you add this setting: `"search.useIgnoreFiles": false,` and see if the search works then?

Comment: Many thanks but no luck...it is quite key to coding that find functionality!

Comment: @atreeon why did you accept this answer if it doesn't answer your question?