# VSCode: How do I search and replace text in only opened files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to replace some text in **only the files that are currently opened**.

Such as my project contains `a.html`, `b.html` and `c.html`; but I opened only `a.html` and `b.html`, so the replace won't affect `c.html`

Is there a way to find and replace the occurrences at once instead of going through those files one by one?

Comment: But I need to replace just opened files, not the whole project...

Comment: @HaoWu kindly check my updated answer

Comment: @HaoWu click the three dots it will show files to include and exclude. In that you type your files names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search only in currently open files in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011289/how-to-search-only-in-currently-open-files-in-vscode) (specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851872/2745495) that shows new experimental feature in VS Code 1.53)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you add `./` in *files to exclude* it will only look in open files.

[image: Search/replace screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use this panel in VS Code (in the menu choose "Edit > Replace in Files") and replace all occurrences in project files. And you can also specify files to *include* and files to *exclude*.

Here is a shortcut to open "Replace in Files" panel:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: It works, thanks! I just wish there's a better way to do this, that I still need to type in all the opened file names...